# how join post with terms one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

i try to join my post table rows with terms table, my database post and database structure is same as wordpress, i don't know how join one row with multiple rows;

CLEAR Example:

post table :

```
post_id
post_title
post_content
post_dateline
post_owner
```

terms table:

```
term_id
term_name
term_title
term_type
```

term_relationships table:

```
post_id
term_id
```

Now i have :
a post with id value 3;
three terms with id values (4,6,7)

term_relationships rows like:

```
  post_id      term_id
     3            4
     3            6
     3            7
```

is possible get all these information with one query, or i should first query posts, then try get terms information?

Comment: There's the mysql group_concat() function if you NEED to return a single row, but you'd probably be better off using a separately query to fetch the post/terms relationships.

Comment: why don't you have post_id column in terms table?

Comment: i use term_relationships like wordpress, because one post have multiple terms

Comment: The best result would probably be to split it 2 separate queries.

Comment: you don't have to use table with relationships data. just add "post_id" column to terms table. and there would be several rows with same "post_id" value. then you will use simple JOIN. or let us know what do you need it for. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT function of mysql it will join multiple rows to a single row but give you the result as a comma seperated field.

Comment: i use two query, first of all select all terms, then use group_concat to ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The type of join you look for is LEFT JOIN. Something like this:

```
Select * from post p
left join term_relationships r on r.post_id = p.id
left join terms t on t.term_id = r.term_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, try:

```
select * from post_table p
left join terms_table t on p.post_id = t.term_id
```

or, another option might be:

```
select *, (select term_id from term_table where term_id=p.post_id) from post_table p
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a join with your mapping table and add data using left joins on both tables?

```
SELECT * FROM  term_relationships 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN terms ON term_relationships.term_id = terms.term_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON term_relationships.post_id = posts.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need it for? I think getting it using one query is quite counter-productively.

Why do not use two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM posts;
SELECT * FROM terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM term_relationships WHERE post_id = $post_id);
```

> sorry for my english